# assign value of type 'JSON' to type '[JSON]'

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview and data saved in JSON on var data = JSON
and I tried to save the same data to another view with same type but it gives error **"Cannot assign value of type 'JSON' to type '[JSON]'"**

```
var data = [JSON]()    
 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                    
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecAdsViewController") as? SecAdsViewController else { return }
    vc.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

on the second view

```
var data = [JSON]()
```

Comment: in you want to perform the particular object then use   **var data: JSON = ()** on your second view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your first view you are used the array of dictionary using swiftyJSON, once user tapped the cell you want to move the one dictionary to second view, so in your second view you need to create the dictionary not a array,

```
var data: JSON = [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to assign a single instance of JSON to a var that's an array, you must append (or insert)

```
vc.data.append(self.data[indexPath.row])
```